# Jenkins war deployment to Tomcat 7

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm using Jenkins for war deployment to my remote server which uses Tomcat 7.
I need my application to be directly installed at dedicated port like this:

```
http://localhost:8083
```

instead of usual:

```
http://localhost:8080/myCoolApp
```

To achieve this I deploy my war archive as ROOT directly to 'webapp' Tomcat's directory. 
Everything works fine, archive is sent and deployed but I get an error from Jenkins:
[image]

Just to remind - archive is deployed successfully! 
But as a perfectionist I just can't stand a result like this.

Here is my configuration for Jenkins deployment: 
[image]

Here is Tomcat configuration for my application as a separate service:

```
  <Service name="Jangel">  

      <Connector port="8083" protocol="HTTP/1.1"  
          connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />  

      <Engine name="Jangel" defaultHost="localhost">  

          <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase" />  

          <Host name="localhost" appBase="Jangel" unpackWARs="true"  
              autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
          </Host>  
      </Engine>
```

So the question is - how should I configure correctly Tomcat&Jenkins?

Or how may I avoid/silence this Jenkins error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this by replacing the context path in your jenkins deployment by / (slash) instead of writing ROOT.